# uTypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Tags: python

I get this error:

> uTypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

From this code:

```
print "what is your name?"  
x=raw_input()
print "Are you woman or man?"
y=raw_input()
print "how old are you?"
z=raw_input()
print "at what age did you or will you first travel in an plane?"
f=raw_input()

print "This is a story about a ",y," named ",x
print z-f ,"years ago",x, " first took an airplane."
print " the end"
```

Why?

Comment: Rolled back so that the question matches the answers; @user1240834, please open a new question if you have a new question instead of editing this one.

Answer (score 4):

Your variables `z` and `f` are strings. Python doesn't support subtracting one string from another string.

If you want to display a number, you're going to have to convert them to either floats or integers:

```
print int(z) - int(f),"years ago",x, " first took an airplane."
```

The reason these are strings in the first place is because `raw_input` [always returns a string](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Answer (score 2):

[`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string, so basically you end up with this:

```
print '20'-'11'
```

Since you cannot subtract one string from another, you need to convert them to numbers first.

Try this:

```
z = float(raw_input())
...
f = float(raw_input())
```

Secondly, use descriptive variable names instead of x, y, z and f, so something like:

```
age = float(raw_input())
...
firstPlaneTravelAge = float(raw_input())

print age-firstPlaneTravelAge, ...
```

Also note that this code has no validation, it will crash if the user enters something which isn't a number.